# ReactJS: Getting inputs from form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, react-redux, text-rendering

I am currently trying to get the complete input from a user in a form using React. I need to get these inputs and then store them so that I can pass these values to another function. Currently, I have been trying to use uncontrolled inputs without success, but have also tried controlled inputs without any success either. Any ideas? I have to pass these values to the function `peopleContract.addPerson(this._firstName, this._lastName, this._email, {from: accounts[1], gas: 3000000})`

Here is the code (commented is the controlled input approach):

```
import React from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3';

//Declaring the ethereum client (initializing) with the url in which the testrpc is running
var ETHEREUM_CLIENT = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"))

//These could be dynamically added through input fields, but hard coding for now
var peopleContractABI = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getPeople","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"people","outputs":[{"name":"firstName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"lastName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"email","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_firstName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_lastName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_email","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"addPerson","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]

var peopleContractAddress = '0xb1a711f4e1250761b85be7bb4478c07d256b8225'

var peopleContract = ETHEREUM_CLIENT.eth.contract(peopleContractABI).at(peopleContractAddress)

//Need to create a variable named accounts in order to know which account
//to make the transactions from
var accounts = ETHEREUM_CLIENT.eth.accounts

//Creating the dynamic input fields for the user to input his/her data
export class Form extends React.Component{
  handleSubmitClick = () => {
    const firstName = this._firstName.value;
    const lastName = this._lastName.value;
    const email = this._email.value;
    //do something with these variables
  }

/*
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({[key]: event.target.value});
  }
*/

/*
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A user was submitted: ' + this.state.firstName + this.state.lastName + this.state.email);
    event.preventdefault();
*/

/*
    if((this.state.firstName==!"") && (this.state.lastName==!"")&& (this.state.email==!"")){
        peopleContract.addPerson(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName, this.state.email, {from: accounts[1], gas: 3000000})

        // after you subimt values clear state
        this.setState({
            firstName: this.state.firstName,
            lastName: this.state.lastName,
            email: this.state.email
        })
    }else{
        // render error
        alert('Some fields are mandatory');
    }
}
*/

/*
  componentWillMount(){
    peopleContract.addPerson(this._firstName, this._lastName, this._email, {from: accounts[1], gas: 3000000})
  }
  */


  render() {
    peopleContract.addPerson(this._firstName, this._lastName, this._email, {from: accounts[1], gas: 3000000})
    return(
      <form>
      <div>
        <h4>Name</h4>
          <input
            type="text"
            ref={input => this._firstName = input} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>Last Name</h4>
          <input
            type="text"
            ref = {input2 => this._lastName = input2} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>Email</h4>
          <input
            type="text"
            ref = {input3 => this._email = input3}  />
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmitClick}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what error you got?

Comment: It tells me I am not passing the required arguments to the function, which should be free, which means I need to store the inputs somehow

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the refs before they are assigned in the render function.

It seems like you want to call `peopleContract.addPerson()` on submit so it should look like this

```
export class Form extends React.Component{
  handleSubmitClick = () => {
    const firstName = this._firstName.value;
    const lastName = this._lastName.value;
    const email = this._email.value;

    peopleContract.addPerson(firstName, lastName, email, {from: accounts[1], gas: 3000000})
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <form>
      <div>
        <h4>Name</h4>
          <input
            type="text"
            ref={input => this._firstName = input} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>Last Name</h4>
          <input
            type="text"
            ref = {input2 => this._lastName = input2} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>Email</h4>
          <input
            type="text"
            ref = {input3 => this._email = input3}  />
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmitClick}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: binding is not required, OP is using [**property initilizer syntax**](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/es7-property-initializers).

Answer (score 0):

By using [ref callback](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) we store the reference of dom element, As per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

> When the ref attribute is used on an HTML element, the ref callback
>   receives the underlying DOM element as its argument. For example, this
>   code uses the ref callback to store a reference to a DOM node:

```
ref = { (input) => { this.textInput = input; }} />
```

To get the values of uncontrolled component using [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) you need to write:

```
this._firstName.value,    //value

this._lastName.value,     //value

this._email.value         //value
```

Another change is remove this line from render method:

```
peopleContract.addPerson(this._firstName, this._lastName, this._email, {from: accounts[1], gas: 3000000})
```

Because during initial rendering ref will not be available, so it you try to access the value before rendering it will throw error.

> The ref attribute takes a callback function, and the callback will be
>   executed immediately **after the component is mounted or unmounted**.

Check the working solution:

```js
class Form extends React.Component{

  handleSubmitClick() {
    const firstName = this._firstName.value;
    const lastName = this._lastName.value;
    const email = this._email.value;
    console.log(firstName, lastName,email);
    peopleContract.addPerson(firstName, lastName, email, {from: accounts[1], gas: 3000000})
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <form>
      <div>
        <h4>Name</h4>
          <input
            type="text"
            ref={input => this._firstName = input} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>Last Name</h4>
          <input
            type="text"
            ref = {input2 => this._lastName = input2} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>Email</h4>
          <input
            type="text"
            ref = {input3 => this._email = input3}  />
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmitClick.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Form/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: I have tried doing this but it won't work, it says that it cannot read the property value of undefined

Comment: reason is, since you are making that call inside render method and during first rendering ref will not present.

Comment: I have tried using componentWillMount but it doesn't work either

Comment: where you want to make that call inside form submit?? check the updated answer all the values we can access inside handle submit function.

Comment: I want to be able to store these values and then pass them to a function

Comment: check the working code, do the call inside handlesubmit function.

Comment: @jh5614 glad it solved you issue, accept the answer. Check this how to accept answer and why ? [**LINK**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/356729)